Tagging a node with a style leads to the previous node being overwritten
I write a graph in VS Code with the extension "Mermaid Editor" (Extension ID: tomoyukim.vscode-mermaid-editor).
I want to create a graph and tag the nodes so that I can style each tag separately.
When I tag a node with e.g. t_blaetter(NODE_NAME) it overwrites the previous tagged node so that in my example t_blaetter(tbl_publisher) overwrites t_blaetter(tbl_article) leading to t_blaetter(tbl_article) missing in the graph, same goes for subdependencies:
t_dashboard(COCKPIT) --> t_blaetter(tbl_publisher) --> bq(website_analytics)
overwrites
t_dashboard(COCKPIT) --> t_blaetter(tbl_article) --> bq(article_analytics)
leading to t_blaetter(tbl_article) and bq(article_analytics) missing in the graph.
This code:
flowchart TD;
    %% Styles
    style t_arbeitsmappe fill:#d9ead3,stroke:#000
    style t_dashboard fill:#d9ead3,stroke:#000
    style t_blaetter fill:#d9ead3,stroke:#000
    style bq fill:#f665,stroke:#f66

    %% COCKPIT
    t_arbeitsmappe("CR_COCKPIT") --> t_dashboard(COCKPIT);
                                     t_dashboard(COCKPIT) --> t_blaetter(tbl_article);
                                                              t_blaetter(tbl_article) --> bq(article_analytics);
                                     t_dashboard(COCKPIT) --> t_blaetter(tbl_publisher);
                                                              t_blaetter(tbl_publisher) --> bq(website_analytics);

should create the following graph:
CR_COCKPIT --> COCKPIT --> tbl_article   --> article_analytics
CR_COCKPIT --> COCKPIT --> tbl_publisher --> website_analytics


but creates this graph instead:
CR_COCKPIT --> COCKPIT --> tbl_publisher --> website_analytics



This is because your code is using the same node id multiple times, with different labels. Since they have the same ID, mermaid sees them as the same object, and will not create a new node
t_blaetter(tbl_article)
This will create a node with the id of t_blaetter, and the label tbl_article
In order to use the style the flowchart using the syntax you are trying to use, the style lines would have to be after the elements are defined, and then use the nodeId to tell mermaid which styles to use.
flowchart TD
    t_arbeitsmappe("CR_COCKPIT") --> t_dashboard("COCKPIT")
    t_dashboard --> t_blaetter1("tbl_article") & t_blaetter2("tbl_publisher")
    t_blaetter1 --> bq1("article_analytics")
    t_blaetter2 --> bq2("website_analytics")
    style t_arbeitsmappe fill:#d9ead3,stroke:#000
    style t_dashboard fill:#d9ead3,stroke:#000
    style t_blaetter1 fill:#d9ead3,stroke:#000
    style t_blaetter2 fill:#d9ead3,stroke:#000
    style bq1 fill:#f665,stroke:#f66
    style bq2 fill:#f665,stroke:#f66

However, since you are using the same styles with more than one node, using classDef might be more what you are looking for, as you would only have to define the CSS once, and assign it to any node you want to use that style using :::
flowchart TD
    t_arbeitsmappe("CR_COCKPIT") --> t_dashboard("COCKPIT")
    t_dashboard --> tbl_article["tbl_article"] & tbl_publisher["tbl_publisher"]
    tbl_article --> article_analytics["article_analytics"]
    tbl_publisher --> website_analytics["website_analytics"]
     
    t_arbeitsmappe:::class1
    t_dashboard:::class1,class1
    tbl_article:::t_blaetter
    tbl_publisher:::t_blaetter
    article_analytics:::bq
    website_analytics:::bq

    classDef class1 fill:#d9ead3,stroke:#000
    classDef bq fill:#f665,stroke:#f66


